# Turn a .dll rcon connection into a array for more than one connection instance?

Tags: c#

I'm learning and have a .dll Rcon that I use and want to have two of more connections on the same form.

i create a connection to the .dll Rcon I use this:
public Grcon Sr = new Grcon();

How to I convert the .dll code or .dll file to use more than one connection turning the Grron to to a array to have. Grcon[0] and Grcon[1]

Comment: Something like `public Grcon Sr1 = new Grcon(); object[1] SrArray = new Object[1];SrArray[0] = Sr;SrArray[1] = Sr1;`

Comment: Thank you! The Help may seem like a dumb question to most. Looking for a good site to learn from that's cheap gives me something to do during chemo treatment.

Comment: Read Jon Skeets book, sorry to hear that man, my sister made it through it (f'n tough time), I wish you a speedy recovery

Comment: To use the array you will need to cast it back to a Grcon.. eg: `((Grcon)SrArray[1]).SomeMethodOrProperty;`

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. Cancer treatment is ruff but I'm going to survive it. I won't give up!